# Add Layout Identifier in Magento Admin-Panel

Tags: xml, magento, layout

I'm trying to create a Magento Theme. So far I copied RWD and modified it to my wishes. But now I've run into a problem. I'm trying to change the available layouts in the Admin Panels "Edit Page -> Design" tab. It only lists "Empty, 1 column, 2 columns with left bar, etc.". I want to add another layout to this exact list, but I have been unable to find the respective xml file to modify. The page.xml lets me add layouts, but they don't show up in the drop-down list. I grep-ed all files for the "1 column" texts, but none showed up. Where do I have to look to find the configuration for this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a custom module for that:

Register your module:

```
app/etc/modules/Dropdown_Layout.xml
```

and insert

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dropdown_Layout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Page />
            </depends>
        </Dropdown_Layout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

You see that our module depends on the Mage_page core module.

Create the config file:

```
app/code/local/Dropdown/Layout/etc/config.xml
```

and insert

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Dropdown_Layout>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Dropdown_Layout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts> 
                <newlayout module="page" translate="label">
                    <label>newlayout</label>
                    <template>page/newlayout.phtml</template>
                    <layout_handle>newlayout</layout_handle>
                </newlayout> 
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Dropdown_Layout>
                    <file>Dropdown_Layout.xml</file>
                </Dropdown_Layout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

The layout file that you referenced in the config file

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/your_theme/layout/dropdownlayout.xml
```

and insert

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<layout>
    <newlayout translate="label">
        <label>newlayout</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/newlayout.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
    </newlayout> 
</layout>
```

And the actual html file:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/your_theme/template/page/newlayout.phtml
```

and insert your html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="top" class="no-js">
    <head>
        ...
```

Assign the template:
[image]